# Python packaging - Top level import behaving strangely

Tags: python, import, packaging

I am currently having a problem with python packaging and references to that.

My structure is as follows:

```
code/
    package/
        A/
            __init__.py
            a.py
            aa.py
        B/
            __init__.py
            b.py
            bb.py
        C/
            __init__.py
            b.py
            bb.py
        __init__.py     #1
documentation/
    ...
other_stuff/
    ...
```

(All `__init__.py` are empty)

According to everything I have read, I should be able to reference and import things like this (in a.py):

```
from package.B.bb import whatever
```

However, this does not work. When I duplicate the outer `__init__.py` to the 'code' folder, I can import things like this, however:

```
from code.package.B.bb import whatever
```

This is obviously non-ideal for most actual uses.

What is it I can do to achieve my target behaviour? (I'm assuming it's something simple which I am just missing)

(Some more details: I am using Python 2.7 and PyCharm 4.03)

Comment: I've moved up the `__init__.py` you marked as `#1` to be located *inside* the `package` directory, not just next to it. That fits with your question description, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the *parent directory* of `code` listed on `sys.path`, but you need to have the `code` directory *itself`added to`sys.path`.

In other words, you need to have `/full/path/for/code` in `sys.path`, not just `/full/path/for`.

Note that Python automatically adds the *current working directory* or the *parent directory of a script* to `sys.path`; see the various options listed in the [Command Line Interface Options documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options).

For example, a Python script located inside `code`, when run with `python path/for/code/script.py` will have the `code` directory added to `sys.path` for that run.

Comment: This completely solved my problem. To be more concrete, I changed the pycharm root (settings -> project: X -> Project structure to use /full/path/for/code. Thank you.